# A (possibly TV) movie about a squad that goes back in time from an uninhabitable Earth to 20th century to rewrite history

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, tv

I'm looking for this movie that I've watched on cable TV when I was younger but I can't seem to find it anywhere in lists on the Internet.

It's probably from the 90s. It was more of a TV movie or those that are released direct to video. It was an American film.

The plot was that in the future the human race was a some sort of military dictatorship or something, people live in giant spaceships (I might be confused but I think the Earth was a dead uninhabitable rock).

Then a guy (which is the villain) goes to the past and wants to rewrite history. Then a squad of soldiers follow him with their spaceship to the past. There was also a female soldier.

They fight in the present 20th century. (I think the evil villain guy was trying to make some sort of cult or an organization and change history but again I might be confused)

There were some scenes when the squad had to steal a vehicle and I think they didn't know how it worked. They had some sort of what looked like a portable computer but it looked more like a big bulky satellite phone. (It's a movie from the 90s, haha)

I don't remember how and what happened to defeat the villain but after that they had a moral dilemma to do something and they did the right thing.

Then they returned to the future to find out that they have changed it and now the Earth was still habitable. They weren't on a military spaceship any more but on a civilian ship which is going to Earth and the world was a some sort of Utopia.

I know it's not much but I gave it a try. Maybe someone will recognise and remember it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could be [TOTAL REALITY (1997)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/total_reality/)

> A soldier must confront the past to save the future in this sci-fi adventure. In the year 2128, the Earth has become a battleground, where the forces of fascist leader Gen. Tunis (Thomas Kretschmann) have been beaten into submission. However, the victory of the anti-fascist Alliance has come at the expense of much of the planet, which has been laid to waste by Tunis's forces. Refusing to surrender, Tunis instead finds a way to travel back in time to the late 1990s, where he formulates a plan to alter history to his advantage -- and put the fate of the world in jeopardy. However, Lt. Anthony Rand (David Bradley), an Alliance soldier who fights bravely but by his own rules, gets wind of Tunis's scheme; with the help of a group of condemned prisoners, Rand follows Tunis back in time in a desperate effort to save mankind's future.

### Trailer

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55764/soldiers-in-spaceship-travel-into-the-past-to-stop-a-religious-book-from-being-w/55841#55841